# Display only one day after the previous day is selected in datetimepicker bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a From and to date in bootstrap datetimepicker in my form. Like this
[Date picker in my Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzN4c.jpg)

And i need get to display only one day in To(Date) after the from(Date) is selected
can anyone help me to display it

This is my previous code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        // stepping: 30,
        //daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 5],
       // minDate: moment(new Date(), "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm").add(3, 'days'),
          minDate: moment(new Date(), "YYYY-MM-DD"),
        //enabledHours: [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
        useCurrent: false
      //  autoclose: true
    });
 $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
        //stepping: 30,
        //minDate: moment(new Date(), "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm").add(3, 'days'),
          minDate: moment(new Date(), "YYYY-MM-DD"),
        //enabledHours: [`enter code here`9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
        useCurrent: false,
        keepOpen: false
    });
```